# Limit where the function has a different definition on $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\backslash\Bbb Q$

Tags: limits

Compute $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to0}f(x)}$, where $f$ is defined by

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x^2 & \quad x \in \Bbb Q \\
            x & \quad x \notin \Bbb Q
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

I said that the limit is $0$, as plugging $0$ into $x^2$ works and approaching $0$ from the left and the right of $x$ (irrespective of whether $f$ is continuous) works.

Comment: Yes, the limit is zero.

Comment: This function is only continuous at $0$ and $1.$ Hence $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} F(x) = F(0) = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Claude Arbaut. Sorry I made a typo in the previous edit.